# How to filter Hashmap to update the value on the fly using Java 8 stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a scenario and I am not sure what possibly could be the effective way to filter hashmap and update the same map. Here is my hashmap;
`Map<Double, List<Product>> mappedProducts = new HashMap<>();`
I have put out the keys and values in mappedProducts in some method. Now in another method, I am trying to filter out the list of products based on if my key value is bigger than product's property weight. This is how I have done it, though it works perfectly fine but I am not sure if this is the most effective and efficient way to do it. Have a look at the following code;

```
this.mappedProducts.entrySet().stream().filter(packList ->{
        mappedProducts.put(packList.getKey(), packList.getValue().stream().filter(pack ->{
                if(pack.getWeight() <= packList.getKey())
                    return true;
                return false;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return true;
    }).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
System.out.println("Filtered Products"+mappedProducts);
```

Is there any other better way to get this done?

Comment: Seems to me like you want your code reviewed. Maybe [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is more appropriate?

Comment: Filter map to retrieve a subset, and update keys is not the same

Comment: @azro updating keys? it is no where needed nor discussed over here. I have List of Products as value and need to remove some products from list based on some criteria. that's it...Did you mean, I dont need to use map.put(key, value) within the filter? If that's so how else I can do it?

Comment: To me you're updating a map you're iterating over

Comment: `mappedProducts.entrySet() .removeIf(packList -> packList.getValue().stream() .anyMatch(pack -> pack.getWeight() > packList.getKey()));`

Comment: @Holger thanks.. it looks more elegant and does work too by making a small change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a filtered new map  : *Keep the entries where all product have a weight less then the key*

```
Map<Double, List<Product>> filtered = mappedProducts.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(packList -> packList.getValue().stream().allMatch(pack -> pack.getWeight() < packList.getKey()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

If you want to modify the main map: *Remove all entries where one product have a weight higher than the key*

```
mappedProducts.entrySet()
              .removeIf(packList -> packList.getValue().stream().anyMatch(pack -> pack.getWeight() > packList.getKey()));
```